# Google Chrome does not open application on Deep Link on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, deep-linking

Google Chrome wouldn't launch my app on Deep Link, however, the app gets launched if I run it from Firefox. I use "onkat://" just as an example as I just want to get the app launched first.

Following is the code in my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize|orientation"
            android:icon="@drawable/something"
            android:label="@string/appName"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="user" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="onkat"/>

            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Any ideas? If Google Chrome requires anything more in the Intent-filter? or a work-around. I tested on multiple devices, except Chrome the other browsers run my app when I simply enter "onkat://"

Observation: I think Google Chrome doesn't work with Deep Link in general. Even Facebook deep link doesn't work on it, while it works on other browsers (fb://). Also, google chrome Deep Link doesn't work for iOS

Comment: issue is fixed in chrome,i am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 14):

Chrome has changed how it handles intents launched from the Chrome browser app.

`<a href="intent://scan/#Intent;scheme=zxing;package=com.google.zxing.client.android;end"> Take a QR code </a>`

The answer can be found here: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Comment: this is my data, <data android:host="dtx.com.test" android:port="9999" android:scheme="test" /> and I formed the href like this, <a href="intent://dtx.com.test/#Intent;scheme=test;package=com.test.android;end"> Open the App </a> , but it is not working.

Comment: From chrome browser, always open google playstore, even though the app is installed.

Comment: Tried the same implementaion when opening the link from chrom browser  always open the playstore app and direct to app,is there way to fix this ?

Comment: @Manikandan <a href="test://dtx.com.test:9999"> Try this deeplink instead.

Comment: What if I want to do it without a user click (when page loads for example)

Answer (score 9):

In the manifest file your intent filter should be like this:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="productlist"
                android:path="/"
                android:scheme="westwing" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and on the browser side it should be like this:

```
"intent://productlist/#Intent;scheme=westwing;package=de.westwing.android;end"
```