# How to use the React Navigation Deep linking in Android

Tags: react-native

I succeded to add the **Deep Linking** feature on my React Native app 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html#docsNav

The problem is **when I send the email to Android users**.

On iOS:

- they receive an email,
- copy the link `appname://user/david`
- Paste it to Safari
- I have the alert prompt *Open the app*

On Android:

- they receive an email,
- copy the link `appname://appname/user/david`
- Paste it to Chrome
- Chrome is doing a search on Google and don't ask to open the app

PS: If I use my terminal with
`adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d 'appname://appname/user/david' com.company.appname` I have no problem.

The thing is the Quality Assurance Team can't test it in *real-life* flow

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189172/google-chrome-does-not-open-application-on-deep-link-on-android

Comment: Seams I need to use __Android Intents with Chrome__


> you should implement a user gesture to launch the app via a custom scheme, or use the “intent:” syntax described in this article.


https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Comment: Thank you @TareqEl-Masri I tried the solution with the `intent://` but if you copy/paste the link on Chrome the behavior is a search, not _Open the app_

Comment: in debug deep linking working properly but in release didnt work.
they show can't open url and invalid address