# React Native Deep Linking Application Not Opening

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking, react-native-navigation

I followed all the steps from both the articles mentioned below

https://hackernoon.com/react-native-deep-linking-for-ios-and-android-d33abfba7ef3

https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e

After the app gets installed on my phone, I tried opening the app from the browser by giving the URL as peopleapp://people/1 format. Instead of opening the app, the browser opens Google search to search for the above.

I Used this application to open my Application by using my App Link(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manoj.dlt&hl=en_US) it's working.

But how to open the application from browser or from another application Using my App Link ?

Anyone has idea, how to solve this issue ?

Here is my Total AndroidManifest Code`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="whizzard" android:host="article" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

`

My Link is whizzard://article

Comment: Please post the code you used, not the link.

Comment: which browser have you tried the deeplink?

Comment: @RishiRaj from Chrome or from another apps Like slack,gmail.

Comment: @hongdevelop added now Manifest File too,can you please check now

Comment: @PraveenReddyVangala [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189172/google-chrome-does-not-open-application-on-deep-link-on-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per google docs:

The functionality has changed slightly in Chrome for Android, versions 25 and later. It is no longer possible to launch an Android app by setting an iframe's src attribute. For example, navigating an iframe to a URI with a custom scheme such as paulsawesomeapp:// **will not work** even if the user has the appropriate app installed. Instead, you should implement a user gesture to launch the app via a custom scheme, or use the “intent:”.

You can read more about how intents work [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents). However, the tutorial you followed, for deeplinking **will work** on other **browsers** which are **not chrome or chrome based**.

Comment: can this be done using firebase dynamic links or not ?