# Zxing Android app won't open from website

Tags: javascript, android, zxing

I trying to launch the zxing barecode scanner from website. It used to work 1 or two years ago.

Simple code is a `window.location = "zxing://scan/?ret...";`

The console in Chrome output: `the destination zxing... was blocked.`.

I call the URL from IP without TLS.

Is it because it's an old app, browser restriction or phone (Samsung A50)?

**EDIT**

I have created a website (with s3 static website). I confirm the app is working using Firefox for Android but not with Chrome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome has a new way of handling deeplink: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

Answered in [Google Chrome does not open application on Deep Link on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189172/google-chrome-does-not-open-application-on-deep-link-on-android)